# i have a problem on including hooks to a morpion game on React tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tic-tac-toe

i'am trying to resolve tutorial of react using states and hooks ,but i'am sure that i'am missing something , i can't obtain content , need your help , I am beginner
i'll join my code

```
function Game () {
  const [history,setHistory]= useState[{squares:Array(9).fill(null)}]
  const [xIsNext,setXIsNext]= useState('true')
  const [stepNumber,setStepNumber]= useState(0)
  const [current,setCurrent]=useState(null)
  const [winner,setWinner]=useState(null)
          const handleClick = (i) =>{
         history = history.slice(setStepNumber(stepNumber +1));
         current = history[history.length - 1];
        const squares = current.squares.slice();
        if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]){
            return;
        }
        squares[i]= xIsNext ? 'X':'O';
        setHistory(history.concat([{squares:squares}]));
        setStepNumber(history.length);
        setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
        
        }
    const jumpTo = (step) => {
            return( setStepNumber(step) &&
            setXIsNext(step % 2) === 0
        )};
    const moves = history.map((step,move) => {
        const desc= move ?
        'revenir au tour numero'+ move:
        'revenir au début de la partie';
        return(
            <li key={move}>
                <button onClick={() => jumpTo(move)}> {desc}
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        const history = history;
        const current = history[stepNumber];
       setWinner(calculateWinner(current.squares));
      });  
      let status = null;
      if (winner){
          status = winner +'a gagné'
        }
        else {
          status = 'Prochain joueur:' + (xIsNext ? 'X':'O')
        }
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board 
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={(i) => handleClick(i)}/>
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{status}</div>
            <ol>{moves}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
      }
```

i have this error message
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at Game (index.js:54:1)

Comment: Can you tell us which is the line 54?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function Square({ onClick, value }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const Board = ({ squares, onClick }) => {
  const renderSquare = (i) => {
    return <Square value={squares[i]} onClick={() => onClick(i)} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(0)}
        {renderSquare(1)}
        {renderSquare(2)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(3)}
        {renderSquare(4)}
        {renderSquare(5)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(6)}
        {renderSquare(7)}
        {renderSquare(8)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Game = () => {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([
    {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null)
    }
  ]);
  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (i) => {
      const his = history.slice(0, stepNumber + 1);
      const current = his[his.length - 1];
      const squares = current.squares.slice();
      if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
        return;
      }
      squares[i] = xIsNext ? "X" : "O";

      setHistory(
        history.concat([
          {
            squares: squares
          }
        ])
      );
      setStepNumber(history.length);
      setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
    },
    [history, setStepNumber, setXIsNext, setHistory, xIsNext, stepNumber]
  );

  const jumpTo = (step) => {
    setStepNumber(step);
    setXIsNext(step % 2 === 0);
  };

  const current = history[stepNumber];
  const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

  const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
    const desc = move ? "Go to move #" + move : "Go to game start";
    return (
      <li key={move}>
        <button onClick={() => jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
      </li>
    );
  });

  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = "Winner: " + winner;
  } else {
    status = "Next player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <div className="game-board">
        <Board squares={current.squares} onClick={(i) => handleClick(i)} />
      </div>
      <div className="game-info">
        <div>{status}</div>
        <ol>{moves}</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).